# SelectedValue from dynamically created radiobuttonlist vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a quiz webpage in Visual Studio 2012 and have a little trouble getting the selected value from a dynamically created radiobuttonlist inside a table.

This is how I create the radiobuttonlist (and add it to the table)

```
Dim NewRow As New TableRow
Dim NewCell As New TableCell
Dim rblOptions As New RadioButtonList
rblOptions.ID = "Option" & intQuestion.ToString
NewCell.Controls.Add(rblOptions)
NewRow.Cells.Add(NewCell)
'Questions is a table
Questions.Rows.Add(NewRow)
```

This is how I am trying to get the selectedvalue from the radiobuttonlist after the users hits a button.

```
Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("Option" & intQuestion.ToString), RadioButtonList)

If rbl.SelectedValue.ToString = sdrGetQuestions.Item(0).ToString Then
            intScore += 1
End If
```

In both cases the variable intQuestion = 0.
When running the program I come across the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

On this line:

> If rbl.SelectedValue.ToString = sdrGetQuestions.Item(0).ToString Then

Which I think obviously means the program couldn't find the control it had to place in rbl. I'm couldn't find any answers online...

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you set the `ValueMember` of the RadioButton? If not then the `SelectedValue` will be `Nothing`. It has to be a property of the dataSource.

Comment: How do I do this so the SelectedValue is the text next to the selected radiobutton?

Comment: You use `rbl.ValueMember = {some property on datasource}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my .aspx code.

```
<asp:Table ID="Questions" runat="server">

</asp:Table>
<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" />
```

This is my code behind file code.
I have added dynamic drop-down list.
On save button click, I am retrieving selected value.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim NewRow As New TableRow
    Dim NewCell As New TableCell
    Dim rblOptions As New RadioButtonList
    rblOptions.ID = "Option1"

    rblOptions.Items.Add(New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("1", "1"))
    rblOptions.Items.Add(New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("2", "2"))
    rblOptions.Items.Add(New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("3", "3"))

    NewCell.Controls.Add(rblOptions)
    NewRow.Cells.Add(NewCell)
    'Questions is a table
    Questions.Rows.Add(NewRow)

End Sub

Protected Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    If Page.IsValid Then
        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Questions.FindControl("Option1"), RadioButtonList)

        If rbl.SelectedValue.ToString = "ExpectedValue" Then

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the same error on the same line.
When I hover over the variable 'rbl' is sais 'Nothing' from which I understand it can't find the control (radiobuttonlist).

Comment: I have updated the answer and posted the code I have implemented on my visual studio. Its working fine.

Comment: Still not doing the trick for me...

But I noticed that when I count the rows of table questions right after I made the radiobuttonlist is returns 6.
But when I do this after clicking on the 'save' button it returns 0 (so no rows actually).
I am making a webapplication in VS Express for web, don't know if that changes anything

Comment: I have implemented the same in VS Express for web.
You must be adding dynamic controls in (Not PostBack).
You need to add dynamic control every time a page makes post-back.
So, When button click happens page life cycle events run.
Put your code in PreInit() or Page_Load event.

Comment: How do i do this? Because the code can only be executed after I pressed a first button on the page but before I presse the 'Save' button (on the same page'. Is there any way these dynamic controls can keep existing after a postback?

Comment: For dynamic control generation you need to fully understand the page life cycle.  On Page Load is far to late to be generating your controls.  Like @VirajSanghavi said you need to put this in the preinit.  what is happening is that when you do a post back, by the time you look for the values of the controls, they don't exist.

Comment: THANK YOU, I finally got it to work by adding the control in PreInit like you said.