# Radio button list in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I check if a radio button inside a radio button list is checked?

I used `if radiobuttonlist1.selectedindex > -1` and then I checked a radio button,
but it is not reading the selected, it is always going to the `else` statement.
this is my code:

```
Dim rl1 As RadioButtonList = New RadioButtonList()

If rbl1.SelectedIndex > -1

 Label2.Text = "Checked"

Else

 Label2.Text = "Not Checked" 

End If
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SelectedValue from dynamically created radiobuttonlist vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288548/selectedvalue-from-dynamically-created-radiobuttonlist-vb)

Comment: Well, following the code the code above, at the point of your if statement, nothing is selected in your newly created list box so by falling in to the else, code is functioning as expected.  Is there something missing?

Comment: rl2.Items.Add(New ListItem(qdesc, rl2.ID))  'this is how iam adding to the list. i have added 4 list items in the radio button list

Comment: You declaring a new radio button list in code. That has ZERO to do with the 1 or 5 radio button lists on the form? There is no relationship between that variable you declared and the actual RadioButton list on the form.

Comment: so what do i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You declared your var wrong:

`Dim rl1 As Radio Button List = New Radio Button List()`

should be:

`Dim rl1 As RadioButtonList = New RadioButtonList()`

Comment: i n my code it is as you wrote above but here in the question i wrote it wrong